# Split a line using "Split lines by maximum length" does not generate a result using QGIS

Tags: line, splitting, length

In QGIS I try to split a line of 11.7 km length into segments of 450m plus a rest. I tried to use "Split lines by maximum length", but it just does not work.
For some reason, to the right of the input field for maximum line length, where the unis drop down menu should be, there is only text, saying it's in degrees, with a warning triangle, saying "...in geographic degrees..." but no unit menu. So I cannot change the unit. If I got to "extended" menu -> algorithm settings, it is set to "meters".
I can start the process, it creates an output feature - but this still contains the original single line.

No idea, what goes wrong. I know from tutorial screen shots, there should be a drop-down menu for the length unit.

Any ideas, someone?

Answer (score 3):

Your data is most likely in degree, aka WGS84/EPSG:4326. You're trying to split the line every 450 degree of its length. So, somewhere around 50,000 km.

Reproject your layer to a fitting local CRS, most likely an UTM-Zone, then run the tool again.

Comment: Thanks Erik. 
I guess, you are right. But I must admit: projections are an unknown chapter for me, so I guess, I have to do some reading...
Where would I start?

Comment: Just use the local UTM strip for local projects, or official CRS if available (25832/25833 for Germany e.g.). Worldwide data can be in 4326 or 3857.

Comment: ESRI has some documents for introduction https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/coordinate-systems-and-projections.htm.

Comment: Hi there
Thanks for your help. I managed to reproject the layers and project and splitting works!